# Extracting sentences to another file based on term list

Tags: batch-file, cmd, text-extraction

I have two txt files: one containing a list of phrases (say term.txt) and second, huge file, with a lot of sentences (src.txt). I'm looking for a way to match **one single** sentence to every line from term.txt and extract it to a seperate txt file.

I would like to then copy and paste these in Excel so that there is no "mismatch" between lines (so they parse with each other even if some terms have no matches)

The closest thing that I managed to dig out is:
*findstr /g:term.txt src.txt > done.txt*

But this extracts duplicates and leaves no empty lines if term has no match.
Example:

**Terms:**

suspension

wheel

bushings

**Extracted Sentences based on this terms:**

A *suspension* linkage formed in the shape of an A or V found commonly on the front suspension.

The sides of the two legs of the A-arm are connected to the chassis by rubber *bushings* and the peak of the A-arm is attached to the wheel assembly.

The *suspension* strut is referred to either as a Damper strut or as a MacPherson strut

**Wanted output:**

A *suspension* linkage formed in the shape of an A or V found commonly on the front suspension.

*empty line since no match for wheel*

The sides of the two legs of the A-arm are connected to the chassis by rubber *bushings* and the peak of the A-arm is attached to the wheel assembly.

Is there any way this can be done with some batch file / cmd file? Or something else?

Any help would be very welcome...

Also tried folowing codes:

1 script:

```
$Output = select-string -path "d:\test\src.txt" -pattern "d:\test\term.txt".  
$Output.line | out-file d:\test\outputfile.txt -append
```

2nd Script:

```
$log = get-content d:\test\src.txt   
foreach ($line in $log) {   
    if ($line -like "d:\test\term.txt") {   
$line | out-file -FilePath "d:\test\outputfile.txt" -Append  
 }  
}
```

I'm using Windows.

Comment: Some simple scripts within .bat files, but it doesn't seem to work, only the one mentioned above -findstr- seem to get me some output, definitely doing something wrong:

1 script:
$Output = select-string -path "d:\test\src.txt" -pattern "d:\test\term.txt". 
$Output.line | out-file d:\test\outputfile.txt -append

2nd Script:
$log = get-content d:\test\src.txt
foreach ($line in $log) { 
    if ($line -like "d:\test\term.txt") {
$line | out-file -FilePath "d:\test\outputfile.txt" -Append
    }
}

Comment: Can you precise whether you use Windows or Linux? Your script look like a (Linux) bash script, yet you use Windows paths... And please add your code example to your post using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45513390/edit) button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q45513390.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q45513390_t.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
findstr /g:"%filename2%" "%filename1%" >tempfile.txt
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
 SET "found="
 FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (
  'findstr /L /c:"%%a" "tempfile.txt" '
 ) DO IF NOT DEFINED found (
       SET "found=Y"
       ECHO %%x
      )
 REM use only one of the following lines
 IF NOT DEFINED found ECHO.
 IF NOT DEFINED found ECHO ---%%a--- NOT found
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used files named `q45513390.txt` and `q45513390_t.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Naturally, the tempfile can have whatever name you prefer. I've not deleted it in the code.

First extract the required information to the tempfile, then process the tempfile for each entry in the keywords file, using the `found` flag and `if defined` (which interprets the variable's status at run-time) to control output.

It would have been simpler had your assertion that `wheel` was not in the supplied text been accurate.

Comment: This indeed does what I needed! Thank you very much for your help Magoo